# Max height of ul is limited to a single nested li item

Tags: html, css

Making a slide down drop menu animation, if I set max height to 100% the `<ul>` will only extend its height to the first nested `<li>`. I can set the `max-height` in the Keyframe to 400%, but this causes to animation to go twice as fast in other drop downs with less submenus. The height of the `<ul>` before I hover over seems to be the full size when debugging, not sure why it gets limited in the animation.

And as a secondary question, will I run into browser support issues using animations like this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5k7erme/2/)

```css
@keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
        max-height: 0%;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 400%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#menuTabs {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: #256AAA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
#menuTabs ul {
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    list-style: outside none none;
}
#menuTabs ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    right:50%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    min-width: 170px;
    max-width: 170px;
    position:relative;
}
#menuTabs ul li a {
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:0px 50px;
    line-height:1.3em;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #Blue;
}
#menuTabs ul li:hover > a {
    visibility: visible;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCC;
}
ul#menu li.selected a {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#menuTabs ul li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    max-height: 0%;
}
#menuTabs ul li ul a {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 70px;
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 22px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    background: #256AAA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
#menuTabs ul li ul a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
}
#menuTabs ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    background: #CCC;
}
#menuTabs ul li:hover ul {
    max-height: 0%;
    animation-name: slideDown;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#menuTabs ul li ul li {
    left: 0%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuTabs">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#"> Services</a>

            <ul id="class">
                <li id="srv1"><a href="#"> SubMenu</a>
                </li>
                <li id="srv2"><a href="#"> SubMenu2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> SubMenu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> SubMenu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> SubMenu4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> SubMenu5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For your browser compatability question, check-out http://www.caniuse.com/ (it's a great resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by just using `transition` instead of `keyframes` for that, it runs smoother, and much easier. I haven't found a way to do the *dynamic* height thing, so I think you'll have to pick a height with the max number of items you're possibility going to have.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5k7erme/8/)**

```
#menuTabs ul li ul {
    ...
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
    opacity: .5;
}
#menuTabs ul li:hover ul {
    ...
    max-height: 400%;
    transition: all .25s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
```